# onBackPressed() no funciona

Tags: java, android, webview

Estoy desarrollando una entrega dentro de la webview Android Studio, pero onBackPressed() no funciona. Está cerrando la aplicación.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv.loadUrl("https://delivery.site.com.br/");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setContentView(wv);

        // Geolocalização
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        }, 0);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });
        // Fim da Geolocalização
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(wv.canGoBack()){
            wv.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

El error que es. Perdóname por el código largo, ya que recién estoy comenzando en Android Studio.

```
2022-10-10 08:58:37.940 11807-11807/com.example.delivery E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.delivery.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3803)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2872)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4109)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:601)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6133)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5571)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5763)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5820)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5954)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3221)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2756)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2747)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3198)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7888)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
2022-10-10 08:58:37.945 11807-11807/com.example.delivery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.delivery, PID: 11807
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.delivery.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3803)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2872)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4109)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:601)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6133)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5571)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5763)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5820)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5954)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3221)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2756)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2747)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3198)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:143)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7888)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

¿Cómo puedo arreglar?

Comment: ¿Qué dice la traza del error cuando se cierra la App? Revisa ahí y agrega el texto del error a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Hola A.Cedano. Cambié la publicación poniendo los errores. Perdóname por el extenso código, ya que recién estoy comenzando en Android Studio.

Comment: No pidas disculpas por los errores. Son oro molido cuando se trata de encontrar problemas en el código. Ahí se ve claramente que  tu objeto `wv` es `null` en ese contexto. Entonces, debes verificar por qué es `null`. ¿Tienes un WebView en el layout? No veo que lo estés refiriendo desde el layout ¿? Por lo general, debes tener un WebView y referirlo por su id.

Comment: Dado que esa URL tiene una advertencia de seguridad, prueba con una URL que no tenga ese problema, por ejemplo: `wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");` Es posible que debas poner otras configuraciones ante URLs que tienen advertencias de seguridad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las pautas A.Cedando. Cambié `WebView wv = new WebView(this);` por `wv = new WebView(esto);` Y funciono.

Comment: `new WebView(this)` no debería ser el problema, pues `this` representaría el contexto de la Activity actual, lo cual es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando llamas onBackPressed() , la instancia del WebView tiene valor null:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
> android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference

Lo que sucede es que estas inicializando el WebView en onCreate():

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        ...
        WebView wv = new WebView(this);
```

No definas otra variable, solo usa la que declaraste a nivel de clase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        //WebView wv = new WebView(this);
        wv = new WebView(this);
```